# How to get a linkedhashmap individually from a list of linkedhashmaps

Tags: java, list, maps

I have a list of maps from which i need each map individually for further purposes . here is snippet of code i'm using

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        listOfMaps.add(new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>());
    }

    int j=0;
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        try
        {
            List<Entry<String,Double>> list1 = new ArrayList<Entry<String,Double>>();

            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println(  pairs.getKey() );

            for (int i = 0; i< ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs.getValue()).size() ; i++)
            {
                String docId = ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs.getValue()).get(i).getKey();
                Double ScoreValue = ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs.getValue()).get(i).getValue();
                listOfMaps.get(j).put(docId, ScoreValue);
            }
```

How can i process them separately and i also want to make sure each map is of same size .. how to make sure all the maps in a list are of same size..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small program , I wrote for you
I did n't understand the process logic that is how do you want to process the map
So  I created a separate function of process so that you can insert your logic there

```
static List<Map<String, Double>> listOfMaps = new ArrayList<Map<String, Double>>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            Map map=new LinkedHashMap<String, Double>();
            map.put("serial",i);
            putValues(map);
            listOfMaps.add(map);
        }

        int j = 0;
        Iterator<Map<String, Double>> it = listOfMaps.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {


            Map mapItem = (LinkedHashMap) it.next();
            process(mapItem);
            System.out.println("After processing"+mapItem);

            /*System.out.println(pairs.getKey());

            for (int i = 0; i < ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs.getValue())
                    .size(); i++) {
                String docId = ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs.getValue())
                        .get(i).getKey();
                Double ScoreValue = ((List<Entry<String, Double>>) pairs
                        .getValue()).get(i).getValue();
                listOfMaps.get(j).put(docId, ScoreValue);
            }*/
        }
```